# PHP Password saved by cookie

Tags: php, cookies, passwords, password-protection

I have a password saved by cookie for a webpage. When you enter the correct password, a cookie is saved for three months.

Only with some people it doesn't work and it's not related to browser?
Sometimes it's just saved for as long as the session is on. The links posted down there don't help me at all.

```
  <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['EnterCheck'])) {   
        $CodeOK = $_REQUEST['EnterCode'];
        if ($CodeOK == "PASSWORD"){
            $_SESSION['validUser'] = true; 
            setcookie("PASSWORDSET", "val", strtotime( '+90 days' ), "/");
            header("Refresh:0");
        }
    }
    if(isset($_COOKIE["PASSWORDSET"])){
        $_SESSION['validUser'] = true;                              
    }
    if(!isset($_COOKIE["PASSWORDSET"])){
        $_SESSION['validUser'] = false; 
        echo '<form action="index.php" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="password" name="EnterCode" placeholder="Enter Password" data-required="1"  autofocus> 
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <button type="submit" name="EnterCheck">Password</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>';               
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi, i believe your question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533051/php-session-cookies-to-expire-when-browser-closes) answer provided on stack overflow...

Comment: I'm sorry, but the stuff in this answer does not look different from what I've written in the code?

Comment: I've added seassion parameters outside the if conditions. Could this be the thing?       session_set_cookie_params(30, '/');
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);

Comment: cookie and sessions are both different thing... cookie is set in browser but a session is stored on server... try this ```$CodeOK = $_POST['EnterCode'];
     if ($CodeOK == "PASSWORD"){
            $_SESSION['validUser'] = true; 
            setcookie("PASSWORDSET", "val", time() + (86400 * 90), "/")
            header("Refresh:0");
        }``` .... i have some questions.. 1. why you have 'name' in the button and why are you checking it. How does it helps. 2. if you are manipulating $_SESSIONS the i asume you have started session by calling  ```session_start()``` before